# How to connect Drupal with Keycloak 18 for user creation

Tags: keycloak, drupal-modules, drupal-9, keycloak-connect, keycloak-gatekeeper

I am trying to connect drupal with keycloak for login. I have added client id, client secret  and Keycloak realm , getting from keycloak server.

> Using modules - https://www.drupal.org/project/keycloak
> Link - http://localhost/drupal/user/login

After clicked on the 'Login Keycloak button' , getting error
The website encountered an unexpected error. Please try again later.

Log Message - `Symfony\Component\Routing\Exception\MissingMandatoryParametersException: Some mandatory parameters are missing ("openid_connect_client") to generate a URL for route "openid_connect.redirect_controller_redirect". in Drupal\Core\Routing\UrlGenerator->doGenerate() (line 181 of C:\xampp\htdocs\drupal\core\lib\Drupal\Core\Routing\UrlGenerator.php).`

Please suggest. Thank you.

Comment: Seems it can't find the client-id. Where did you put the contents? Can you post more details about your configurations (by removing confidential details from it)?

Comment: I have instlled keycloak locally, I have created a realm into it. Then in xampp/drupal,

Comment: I am adding  all the data like clientid, secret and all

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like you might have not added the **valid redirect uri** in your local keycloak server page under Clients > Settings which I believe should be "http://localhost/drupal/openid-connect/keycloak" for your project.

And also you need to provide **Keycloak base URL** in your drupal "Configuration > Web Service> Open ID Connect" web page which most of the times if you are using local keycloak server is http://localhost:8080